# Словарь всех русских слов с конкретными существительными

Tags: discussion

Господа, кто-нибудь может подсказать, где можно скачать словарь русских существительных с обозначением разряда? Меня интересуют конкретные существительные:

> Существительные конкретные. Существительные, служащие названиями
>   предметов и явлений реальной, действительности, взятых в отдельности и
>   потому подвергающихся счету. Тетрадь, институт, улица.

Изначально у меня задача выбрать для мнемонического запоминания слово, удовлетворяющее конкретной маске. Например *н*н* или *к*л*. Но выбранные слова должно быть легко запоминать. Например, для первой маски подойдёт как слово "ненависть" так и слово "ананас". Но слово "ананас" гораздо легче представить и, поэтому, привязать к нему мнемоническое правило.

Вот я и подумал, что раз конкретные существительные обозначают определённый предмет, их долждно быть легко представить и запомнить. Где бы мне найти список всех конкретных существительных?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не встречал. Может быть, вам следует копать с другой стороны. Поищите картинный словарь русского языка или переводной картинный словарь с наличием русского языка. Например, [результаты поиска на worldcat.org](http://www.worldcat.org/search?q=su%3aPicture%20dictionaries,%20Russian.&qt=hot_subject) Я бы посмотрел русский индекс в словаре The Oxford picture dictionary : English/Russian. Если они смогли это нарисовать, значит эти существительные - конкретные. Но внимательно просмотрите словарь. Бывают умельцы, которые и совесть могут изобразить.

В словарях иногда указывают исчисляемые/неисчисляемые. Но это может лишь поможет вам отсеять неисчисляемые.

Comment: Спасибо за навдоку! Попробую там покопать.